# PlayFramework 2 - Scala - How to pass the implicit Lang outside the Controller scope

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

In a Play 2.0 application I use Jerkson for custom JSON serialization.

In the implementation of a JsonSerializer class I need to internationalize the messages based on the main language of the browser. Unfortunately the object Lang which is implicit in that context is the JVM language and not that of the Accept-languages ​​of the request.

What is the best way (if any) to access the browser language outside the context of a controller?

```
class LangStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer[LangString] {
  def serialize(string: LangString, json: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {     
    json.writeString(string.localized_value)
  }
//the method localized_value has an implicit parameter Lang and must produce 
//a localized string based on the browser main language.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be passed to your class:

```
class LangStringSerializer(val lang: Lang) extends JsonSerializer[LangString] {
  def serialize(string: LangString, json: JsonGenerator, provider: SerializerProvider) {     
     json.writeString(string.localized_value(lang))
  }
}
```

and you have to retrive it from your controller:

```
def myJsonAction = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(new LangStringSerializer(lang).serialize(...))
}
```

Comment: It is not allowed: method 'serialize' must implement the abstract without it in signature. Moreover, as I said the implicit lang in this point is not the desired one.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why the implicit lang, which usually comes from the controller, is the JVM lang? The language from the browser is the one extracted by the controller method `implicit def lang`, which in turn takes the first one from `request.acceptLanguages`.